# "no function clause matching in Regex.match?/2" when running Ecto migrations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am working on my first Phoenix app and am trying to use Ecto migrations to create my first DB table. However, whenever I try to run migrations with `mix ecto.migrate Repo` I get an error:

```
(elixir) lib/regex.ex:157: Regex.match?(~r/^[^:\/?#\s]+:\/\//, nil)
(ecto) lib/ecto/utils.ex:29: Ecto.Utils.parse_url/1
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/backend.ex:16: Ecto.Repo.Backend.start_link/2
(ecto) lib/mix/ecto.ex:44: Mix.Ecto.ensure_started/1
(ecto) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.migrate.ex:45: Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run/2
(mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:55: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

The error seems unrelated to my migration. I've completely removed the migration file and the same issue happens. I updated all libraries. Nothing changed.

Comment: Which Ecto version are you using? It seems you are using an old one that expects a URL as configuration. If you are using a recent one, please make sure you have configured the repository in the config file.

Comment: Thanks, José, that was totally it. Thank you for helping me out with my noop mistake! You know, when I ask a Ruby question on Stackoverflow I never get a response from Matz ;)

Comment: @whatyouhide Definitely! I've had very little time to work on this, since José responded. As soon as I got it working, I want to do a proper write up of how I migrated from the old Ecto version to the new one.